# How can i calculate position in a matrix with x and y values

Tags: math, matrix, arduino

I have a 4*4 led matrix and each pixel has a value from 0 to 15 counted from left to right. I can only call them with that value

But i want to enter something like
x=3
y=2
And then the led with value 6 will light

I tried x*y but that doesn't work

So how can i calculate this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `x` and `y` range from 0 to 3, the formula is `n=4*x+y`.

Answer (score 0):

You simply could make a large array and make a entery for each x*y